# how to install SML/NJ in Windows without that installer?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

Ok, I know SML/NJ has a self-installing windows `.msi`.

Unfortunately, I can't install it in my office Windows machine as the strict security policy and I don't want to argue with those IT staff for giving me permissions.

So, can I install SML/NJ without the installer, `maybe some zip I can get and just uncompress it for the sml.exe`?

Comment: The boot files for windows i located [here](http://smlnj.cs.uchicago.edu/dist/working/110.75/boot.x86-win32.tgz) if it is an option

Comment: I don't know if this would really work as a long term fix but if you're just writing small programs (solutions to Coursera hw?) then it might be enough: http://www.smlserver.org/smltojs_prompt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. I've put up a build of SML/NJ for Windows in that form at:
http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~larsberg/smlnj.zip

To use it, unzip it to someplace like the desktop and then, in a command prompt (or globally) do:
set SMLNJ_HOME=c:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\smlnj

You should then be able to run sml.bat. Feel free to shoot me questions personally if you run into anything; I am the maintainer of the Windows version of SML/NJ.

Comment: Hey Lars, could you maybe do this again? :) Link is not available, and I can't compile it on my machine - i'm getting gcc compile error